# BootstrapContext is null on ClaimsIdentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity, ws-federation

I have created a new ASP.NET MVC application with .NET 4.5. I have successfully set up authentication with an STS. The authentication flow is working fine and I am able to get the ClaimsIdentity, containing the desired claims, on Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Now I need the bootstrap token to secure the calls to my service layer. I have set the saveBootstrapContext to true on the identityConfiguration element.

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

However, the BootstrapContext property on the ClaimsIdentity is always null.

```
var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var context = identity.BootstrapContext; // context is always null
```

Am I missing anything here? This was supposed to be straightforward :(

Comment: Try it out with `identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First() as ClaimsIdentity`

Comment: Same result with ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First(). It is the same instance of Claimsidentity.

Comment: How did you setup the external authentication? Using the WS-Federation auth module?

Comment: Did you get it working? I added the flag, but still the bootstrapcontext is null.

Answer (score 8):

Solved it by these:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true" />
</system.identityModel>
```

Also need to set `TokenValidationParameters.SaveSigninToken`, **which is distinct from JwtBearerOptions.SaveTokens**:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions {
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            SaveSigninToken = true,               
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is really helpful! it solves my long time puzzle.

Comment: the web config elements didn't do anything for me, but `SaveSigninToken = true` turned out to be critical for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when hosting in IIS Express. It turns out that the issue was my browser - I had not closed all of my browser windows or cleared cookies, so the SessionSecurityToken was not being recreated with the new setting, even though the server had been restarted (the existing FedAuth cookie was still being sent from the browser).

Once I forced a re-authentication by closing all browser windows, restarting the browser and performing my request again, the BootstrapContext was present.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a message handler to manually validate the token using the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to extract a claims principal and attach that to the current Thread, as described here in [Using the JWT handler for Implementing “Poor Man”’s Delegation/ActAs](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas/), when you're validating the token using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken()`, one of the settings on `TokenValidationParameters` is
`SaveBootstrapContext`, setting that `true` does the trick.

Comment: I am using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0, but it does not contain SaveBootstrapContext

Any idea ?

Comment: @Homam I have the same issue and verified `TokenValidationParameters.SaveToken = true` populated theBootstrapContext

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, Version=5.0.4.0, and the setting is this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    // . . .
    o.TokenValidationParameters.SaveSigninToken = true;
})
```